# set a sentinel value for std::map.end() for gcc compiler

Tags: c++, stdmap

Here I specifically only care about the GCC compiler and run time code efficiency.

Consider the following code [try me](https://godbolt.org/z/qY4Y3Y4Yb)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

char Find(const std::map<int, char>& map, int key) {
    auto iter = map.find(key);
    if (iter == map.end()) 
        return 'X';
    return iter->second;
}

char Find2(const std::map<int, char>& map, int key) {
    return map.find(key)->second;
}

int main()
{
    // part 1
    std::map<int, char> x{{0,'0'}, {4,'4'}};
    std::cout << Find(x, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Find(x, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)Find2(x, 3) << std::endl; // returns 0
    std::cout << Find2(x, 4) << std::endl;

    // part 2: Find2 is a shortcut
    std::map<int, char> y(x);
    y.end()->second = 'X';
    std::cout << Find2(y, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Find2(y, 4) << std::endl;
}
```

The *part 2* also works for a GCC compiler I tested in Godbolt, despite it uses the `end()` in a weird way.

In GCC, does map allocate a node `std::pair` to represent the end? Will it be changing when elements are added/deleted? This is related to how the map's `end()` is really implemented, and I am curious to know it.

As many people pointed out, the C++ standard defines it as UB if a the `end()` is dereferenced.

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487108/7026980), which GCC seems to have implemented the map in a way that the `end()` is pointing to a root node. With this I think setting the root node's value to `X` here seems to be a valid operation. Does this mean that the above code should work for GCC?

Comment: `y.end()->second = 'X';` is undefined. `end` does not refer to an element. You shall not dereference it

Comment: Both "part 2" and `Find2` are broken: to deference `end()` is UB

Comment: Code with undefined behaviour is not required to loudly break

Comment: I wonder if a node is allocated (`new`-ed) to represent the `end()`. If yes, then it is not `UB`?

Comment: using a sentinel is rarely a good solution. `char Find` could trhow an exception, or it could return `std::optional<char>` or it could return a `std::pair<bool,it>`

Comment: @doraemon According to this answer <https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299732/5754656>, GNU's libstdc++ and LLVM's libc++ don't allocate an end node (it's a `nullptr`), but MSVC's STL does. That doesn't make this a valid usage (I think STL throws instead of UB)

Comment: if you write code without ub, then it works everywhere with any compiler. You shouldn't write code that relies on implementation details, because they can change

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'd argue that `.end()` *is* a sentinel …

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is, though a sentinel iterator, op wants a sentinel value. An iterator can have a unique value, but any `char` can also appear in the map, hence is not good as sentinel

Comment: the above code runs for linux with gcc. Does it already mean it should not be `nullptr`? I just wanna to understand why it is UB, or why the presence of the sentinel node still makes it UB. If the sentinel node really exists in memory (heap or stack), why cannot I just use it. What is the sentinel node's address?

Comment: [the end element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end)

Comment: If you want to language-lawyer this, then there is a "The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable." in `iterator.requirements.general` in the C++ standard.

Comment: Quoting [cppreference.com's entry on map::end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end) : "Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the map.

This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.".

Comment: "GCC seems to have implemented the map in a way that the end() is pointing to a root node. With this I think setting the root node's value to X here seems to be a valid operation." - You can't rely on that. The next minor library version may (validly) break your assumption. If you write the code like that it is simply buggy.

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency, you should be nowhere near an std::map.

Comment: This looks to me that you only want to get rid of the branch checking if the iterator is valid... Is that _really_ the performance bottleneck of the code you are profiling? To what extent? Like, how much does that represent compared to `find()`?  That aside, if the map is really supposed to contain all elements you will search, wouldn't an `assert(it != the_map.end())` suffice? As it would trigger in debug builds and be optimised out in release builds, this should be enough (assuming, as I said, that you will really just look for elements that are supposed to be in the map).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question refers to how `end()` is implemented for the `std::map` container, I will deal with it, although the idea applies to almost all node-based containers in the libstdc++.

The majority of the `std::map` interface, like the other associative containers, is a wrapper around a `_Rb_tree` object. In the header file there is also the implementation of the base node, `_Rb_tree_node_base`, and the node,`_Rb_tree_node`. The node is a derived class of the base node, to which the storage member is added. To be precise, since C++11 the storage member is no more of type `T`, but is defined with the GCC version of the `std::aligned_storage` type.

The trick is to use an instance of the base node as a sentinel node, which represents both the past-the-last element (by definition, the sentinel node is a specifically designed node that is used as a path traversal terminator) and the before-the-first element. Essentially, the sentinel node is interpreted as both the position after the last element and the position before the first one. The GCC implementation has designed the sentinel node of the `std::map` container in order to keep track of the root element, the leftmost element and the rightmost element using its pointers to the parent, the left child and the right child, respectively.

The original implementation is the following:

```cpp
_Base_ptr&
       _M_root() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent; }

_Base_ptr&
       _M_leftmost() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_left; }

_Base_ptr&
      _M_rightmost() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_right; }
```

Thus, the `_M_header` object is the sentinel node. There are several advantages to using this approach for node-based containers, including the following two:

- since the `end()` iterator points directly to the sentinel node, it is not a dangling pointer and do not exhibits a particular behavior even if the container is empty (in this case, both `begin()` and `end()` refer to the same thing, the sentinel node);
- since the sentinel node is used to represent both the past-the-last position and the before-the-first position, there will always be a valid node before the beginning and after the end and then insert, erase and splice operations can be performed at any position in the same way.

A nice side effect of this implementation is that, if the iterator `end()` is incremented, it will land at the beginning of the container. As aforementioned, the `std::forward_list` container does not have the same features of the other node-based containers as it is not properly a sentinel-node container.

For all other sentinel-node containers, such as `std::list`, the following code is valid:

```cpp
std::list<int> x{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
if(++x.end() == x.begin())
  std::cout << "It works!\n";
```

Trying to dereference the `end()` iterator is UB.

Comment: Nice writeup, but it would greatly benefit from breaking the long paragraphs up into several easier to read paragraphs. That's just a nit, not a knock.

Comment: Thanks very much. I upvoted you answer. But I still have some questions for you to clarify:  what is the root/leftmost/base/m_header node of the tree and parent/left of a node. I didn't see these in [this ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487108/7026980). what is the end() related to the root/leftmost? I would appreciate it a lot if you can provide a graph for them (text based will do). Do you mean that base == root == leftmost when you said:  "use the base node to represent the sentinel of the tree, i.e. the reference to both the root node and the leftmost node in the tree."

Comment: the usage of "base node" and "node base" is also confusion. do they mean `_Rb_tree_node_base`? Or is `base node` a node of type `_Rb_tree_node_base`? "The _M_header member is just an instance of the base node" seems to indicate base node is a type.

Comment: @doraemon, yes, base node is always referred to `_Rb_tree_node_base`. And yes, `_M_header` is an instance of the base node, that is simply a type.

Comment: @doraemon, the base node is not the root of the tree, but an almost-node (it would be a node if it had the `_M_storage` type) that is used as a sentinel, a flag, whose `_M_left` pointer always refers to the root node and `_M_parent` pointer always refer to the lefmost node. However, if the binary search tree is empty, the expression base == root == leftmost becomes true, since the pointers must not remain dangling (then, if no nodes are present, the sentinel ends to refer to itself).